# nodejs rhea npm for amqp couldn't create subscription queue on address in activemq artemis

Tags: node.js, activemq-artemis, rhea

I have an address "pubsub.foo" already configured as multicast in `broker.xml`.

```xml
<address name="pubsub.foo">
   <multicast/>
</address>
```

As per the [Artemis documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/2.0.0/address-model.html):

> When clients connect to an address with the multicast element, a subscription queue for the client will be automatically created for the client.

I am creating a simple utility using rhea AMQP Node.js npm to publish messages to the address.

```js
var connection = require('rhea').connect({ port: args.port, host: args.host, username:'admin', password:'xxxx' });

var sender = connection.open_sender('pubsub.foo');
sender.on('sendable', function(context) {
    var m = 'Hii test' 
    console.log('sent ' + m);
    sender.send({body:m});
    connection.close();
});
```

I enabled debug log and while running the client code I see the message like this.

```
2020-02-03 22:43:25,071 DEBUG [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.postoffice.impl.PostOfficeImpl] Message org.apache.activemq.artemis.protocol.amqp.broker.AMQPMessage@68933e4b is not going anywhere as it didn't have a binding on address:pubsub.foo
```

I also tried different variations of the topic, for example, `client1.pubsub.foo`, `pubsub.foo::client1` however no luck from the client code. Please share your thoughts. I am new to ActiveMQ Artemis.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're observing actually is the expected behavior.

Unfortunately, the documentation you cited isn't as clear as it could be. When it says a subscription queue will be created in response to a client connecting it really means a *subscriber* not a producer. That's why it creates a *subscription* queue. The semantics for a multicast address (and publish/subscribe in general) dictate that a message sent when there are no subscribers will be dropped. Therefore, you need to create a subscriber and *then* send a message.

If you want different semantics then I recommend you use anycast.